# Supplied PAR white oak, one plank has woodworm holes

Tags: oak, insects

I'm a novice woodworker. Ordered £2000 worth of PAR white oak online. One 2m plank of 144x45 has worm holes at 30cm from the end. When ordering I specified I would be cutting to 1m lengths but on pointing this out supplier said don't worry its treated, just fill.

I really don't want to use this piece (in a staircase) and think they should replace, am I being unreasonable?

Comment: What grade (1A, 1B, 2A, 2B?) was the lumber represented as?

Comment: No specific grade, in the product description "Prime solid American white oak planed all round available in 12mm, 15mm, 20mm, 25mm, 32mm, 44mm thick. For use on cabinet & joinery projects,  shelving, window boards, fascias, plinths and thresholds.  The white oak PAR is made from prime grade kiln dried oak and planed to a smooth finish."

Comment: Prime is equivalent in the UK to Appearance Grade 1, and should have no visible defects on a PAR surface.   So, you have a pretty good case that the wood is defective to what was advertised.   A picture of the damage would be helpful to answer the question "is it worth making an issue over?"

Comment: *"and think they should replace, am I being unreasonable?"* Nope! Wormed wood is completely unacceptable to many users, literally won't take it into the workshop/house. The supplier might tell assure you that the worm damage was from before the oak was planked and then kiln dried (which would indeed kill any borers), but how much is such as assurance actually worth? If there does happen to be active woodworm (common furniture beetle) are they going to pay to have your entire house treated??? That isn't a 100% effective process anyway!

Comment: I don't want to over-egg the pudding but I would basically discount everything the seller told me at this point — I mean literally assume they're telling bald-faced lies — so I would be very very concerned about accepting any of it. Unless my own observations led me to be completely certain the holes were revealed by the planking and were not from after sawing and the time in the kiln I would be be returning ALL of the wood, not just the planks with visible worm holes.

Comment: For those silly Americans (like me) that didn't know what PAR wood is, it stands for "Planed All Round" timber - basically the equivalent of S4S (Surfaced on 4 Sides).

Comment: Crosscut area of board with worm holes into strips ~20mm wide, you will soon discover if worms are active! You will lose half of one 2m board, but I would not accept this batch of oak unless I performed this check.

Comment: Thanks, @MattDMo, from another silly American.